# Sending a javascript object to a purescript function

Tags: javascript, purescript

I'm integrating javascript and PureScript like this:

```
  //App.js
  const Calculator = require('../purescript/output/Main/index')

  const config = {
    grossIncome: 128183912,
    married: true
  }

  const result = Calculator.run(config)
```

But I'm not sure how to write the PureScript part to take in a javascript object. We can assume that all inputs are valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The corresponding type definition in PureScript would look like this:

```
type CalculatorConfig = {
    grossIncome :: Int,    -- or should it be Number?
    married :: Boolean
}
```

And the function `run` would look like this:

```
run :: CalculatorConfig -> String
run cfg = if cfg.married then "Married" else "Bachelor"
```

(assuming your result type is a `String`; substitute your actual type here)

---

However, this only works for *pure* functions - i.e. functions that do not produce any side-effects, such as input/output, displaying UI, launching missiles, etc. If your function *does* need to have side-effects, then its return type should be `Effect String` instead of `String`:

```
run :: CalculatorConfig -> Effect String
run cfg = do
   log "Running calculator!"
   if cfg.married then pure "Married" else pure "Bachelor"
```

And in that case, you'd have to call it from JavaScript like this:

```
const result = Calculator.run(config)()
```

See the extra parens at the end? That's how `Effect` is compiled down to JavaScript - as a function. The meaning of this is that `run` returns not a `String`, but a *program* (aka function), which, once executed, will produce a `String`.

---

If you really want to keep the JavaScript unaware of any extra stuff like that, you can export your `run` function as an [`EffectFn1`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-effect/2.0.1/docs/Effect.Uncurried#t:EffectFn1), which is a special wrapper that allows to represent PureScript-style effectful functions as JavaScript-style functions:

```
runImpl :: CalculatorConfig -> Effect String
runImpl cfg = do
   log "Running calculator!"
   if cfg.married then pure "Married" else pure "Bachelor"

run :: EffectFn1 CalculatorConfig String
run = mkEffectFn1 runImpl
```

Or same thing in a shorter way, without a separate definition of `runImpl`:

```
run :: EffectFn1 CalculatorConfig String
run = mkEffectFn1 \cfg -> do
   log "Running calculator!"
   if cfg.married then pure "Married" else pure "Bachelor"
```